# Laravel redirection from private method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a controller that has a method. The code is too long in the method, so I have put some of the codes in other private methods, so that methods become understandable and not make a mess out of it.

Now, when I access the public method from the URL, depending on parameters, it will call a specific private method to process the job. After the job is processed, I want to redirect to a URL, but the redirection is not working.

A sample of my code is as follows:

```
class SomeClass extends BaseController{
    public function getMethodName()
        {
            //check the params and choose a private method to call
            $this->processJob();
        }
    private function processJob()
    {
         //process the job and redirect at the end
         return Redirect::to('some/url');
    }
}
```

The problem is, the above redirect does not work. Why is that? In Codeigniter, when you used `redirect` it works nomatter where it is called from.

If the above code sample is not the right way to do it, would appreciate if someone could show me how it is to be done. Thanks.

Comment: it should work - I use that type of code all the time. Are you getting any errors? what happens if you move the redirect to the beginning of processJob()?

Comment: It does not work. I removed all other codes in processJob(), only keeping that redirect line, still does not work. By the way, am using L4.

Comment: Are you sure processJob is being called? try dd('hi') in processJob - do you see 'hi'??

Comment: Yes processJob() is being called. I tried with exit('hello'); and it displayed 'hello' in the browser.

Comment: what about return $this->processJob()?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to return the return from `$this->processJob()` too.

```
class SomeClass extends BaseController{
  public function getMethodName()
  {
      //check the params and choose a private method to call
      return $this->processJob();
  }

  private function processJob()
  {
     //process the job and redirect at the end
     return Redirect::to('some/url');
  }
}
```

Comment: look at it like this: Laravel calls your controller function and expects something in return, so it knows what to do next. In your code, the `return Redirect::to('some/url');` gets returned to wherever your private function was called, but it doesn't reach Laravel. Yes, sounds a bit stupid, but that's basically what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to redirect to another page from your public function, according to your private function result (I think it's a better solution to make your code more human readable).
But it could works like you wrote it ...