# Laravel constructor redirect is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a controller with several methods and I need to add a specific authorization check on start of each method. So I thought to put this check in constructor as,

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

public function __construct() {
    $this->isAuthorized();
}

protected $layout = "layouts.main";

private function isAuthorized() {
    if (!Session::get('userId')) {
        echo "inside check"; // checking for debug purpose
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}

/**
 * Admin dashboard view after authentication.
 */
public function getDashboard() {
    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.dashboard');
}
```

}

It does not work, it just prints the message inside Session check and load the dashboard page rather than redirecting back to login page.

I have also tried something like this,

```
 public function getDashboard() {
    $this->isAuthorized();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.dashboard');
}
```

When I try to call this method with this weird return statement, then it works

```
public function getDashboard() {
    return $this->isAuthorized();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.dashboard');
}
```

I get that idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926159/laravel-redirection-from-private-method). How do I achieve this using constructor method?

Comment: Why not use a route filter? That's what they're designed to do.

Comment: You can't print any content before sending headers to the browser (in this case, a redirect directive). Remove the `echo` and it should probably work

Comment: I just echoed to check if it comes inside check, it does not work even if i remove echo.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Returning a  `Redirect` to execute it is only possible from routes, controller actions and filters. Otherwise you have to call `send()`

```
Redirect::to('login')->send();
```

[**However you should really use a *filter* for this**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters)

Comment: I am only one week old in laravel, I'll must use the filters if those are designed to accomplish this.

Comment: I strongly recommend it yes :) I also recommend you read the part of the documentation that deals with Laravel's built in authentication. [Here's the link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security)

Comment: Actually I am accepting only login with Google in my admin panel, so I avoided to use built in authentication, I have already read this, it is really great. Thanks for guiding me as well.

Comment: But keep in mind, just because it works it doesn't mean that you should do it (if there's a better way) ;)

Comment: Four years later, and there are no filters anymore in current Laravel 5.6. Instead, check out middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Comment: Getting error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Redirect' not found"

Comment: this is not working correctly in latest laravel 9, I needed to redirect depending on session variable but it was always redirecting weather the variable set or not

Answer (score 5):

Make Sure to use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector; and pass it to the constructor. (Laravel 5.2)

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;

class ServiceController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(Request $request, Redirector $redirect) {
        $this->service = Auth::user()->Service()->find($request->id);
        if (!$this->service) {
            $redirect->to('/')->send();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution worked like charm in Laravel 9.x also. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Event with Illuminate\Routing\Redirector, laravel set redirect in http header, but also continue to execute request like there are no redirect. So the solution is use die() after the redirection.

```
public function __construct(Request $request, \Illuminate\Routing\Redirector $redirecor)
{
    //$bool = ...
    if (false == $bool) {
        $redirecor->action('MyController@myAction')->send() ;
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `->send()`

```
redirect()->route('named-route')->send();
```

insted of `return`

```
return redirect()->route('named-route');
```

in Laravel Constructor.